# strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am write code in for loop , for multiple insert value using codeigniter framework .

this is my code

```
 $oldjoindate = $this->input->post('fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate')  ;
$fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($oldjoindate));

for ($i=0; $i < count($fldWorkHistoryCompanyName); $i++) {
    $data5[] = array(

        'fldUserID' => $insert_id,
        'fldWorkHistoryCompanyName'=>$fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[$i],
        'fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate'=>$fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[$i],
        //'fldWorkHistoryResignedDate'=>$fldWorkHistoryResignedDate[$i],
        'fldCompanyID' => $fldCompanyID

            );
  $this->db->insert_batch('tblWorkHistory',$data5);
}
```

Comment: var_dump($oldjoindate) in the loop and check all its values until the point of error.

Answer (score -1):

Can Yo please check `$fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate` this an array format like $fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[0],$fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[1] ?

```
$oldjoindate = $this->input->post('fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate');
// check db data type is Date ?
$fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($oldjoindate));
// check date is coming proper 
// echo $fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate;
for ($i=0; $i < count($fldWorkHistoryCompanyName); $i++) {
    $data5[] = array(
        'fldUserID' => $insert_id,
        'fldWorkHistoryCompanyName'=>$fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[$i],
        'fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate'=>$fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[$i],
        //'fldWorkHistoryResignedDate'=>$fldWorkHistoryResignedDate[$i],
        'fldCompanyID' => $fldCompanyID
    );
  $this->db->insert_batch('tblWorkHistory',$data5);
}
```

// may be thisis not required `$fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[$i]` simple coming `$fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate`

Comment: normally code is work in single inserting without using array .. but inserting  using for   loop in array not work code display this error strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string my view code is there  <input type="text" class="form-control"   name="fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[]">